# What to call a person who doesn't respect personal space?

Tags: personal-pronouns, personification

What would you call a person that doesn't care for your personal space and is kind-of sticky and doesn't get the hint that people are awkward around him/her and generally avoid him/her?

Comment: Stalker.......?

Comment: ... User 77100?

Comment: When this is reopened I'll add the following answer:   *[limpet](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/limpet)*, “... **someone disregarding or ignorant of another's personal space**”

Comment: @jwpat7 - a limpet is a rock-dwelling mollusk. Do you think this needs to be reopened for this unconventional use? If you do, which is fine, you should present in meta, which will probably get it reopened for you.

Comment: @medica, *limpet* is a traditional literary term for a clingy person or a personal-space-invading person, so the usage I mentioned is not unconventional.

Comment: I'm not exactly poorly read, yet I never heard this use before. Of five dictionaries I just checked, *one* had this meaning. I don't think I'd call it *traditional*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Intruder** and **busybody** may fit you description   I think.

Answer (score 3):

I would call such a person "Clingy".
It is mainly used for people who try to stick around all the time more than you want them to.

Answer (score 2):

That person might be a [Personal Space Invader](https://www.explosm.net/comics/940/)

Answer (score 1):

If this is a case of the person not understanding proxemics, and say, standing too close to you when you talk, I would call him or her a **close talker.**

Answer (score 0):

*Socially inept/clueless.*​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Answer (score -1):

- List item

I would call  him **stubborn**. A stubborn man does not care for our personal space.

Also consider:

**Imposture**